# Textbooks on stochastic calculus and stochastic differential equations

Tags: references, stochastic-processes, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I am looking for key reference books in **stochastic calculus**, **Stochastic Differential Equations (SDEs)** as well as **Stochastic Partial Differential Equations (SPDEs)**, from the most theoretical to the most practical. I know that there is a good book by [J. Michael Steele](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/StochasticCalculus.html) but nothing else.

PS. Related with [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18091/textbooks-on-the-numerical-solution-of-stochastic-differential-equations) question, although different (in my view).

Comment: **Note to answerers:** questions that ask merely for lists of things are generally off topic on all SE sites.  However, when your answer also provides information about the references you recommend, such as their intended audience, what topics they cover, and other *objective, supported* assessments, then your answer has real value.  Since no unique or best answer seems possible, this question has been made Community Wiki.

Comment: +1 to the note above. My experience is that this kind of question attracts answers enumerating the books the users *know*, not what they think of them compared to other books.